# Linux Proxy, How to ensure linux using my proxy settings

Tags: linux, proxy

I just set my proxy in linux as below

export  http_proxy="http://588814:jtubuntu@proxy.abc.com:6050"

Then I pinged google as  ping google.com

It shown the result like this

$ping google.com

PING google.com(172.217.26.206) 56(84) bytes of data

No response from google.

Then I changed the password of proxy to a wrong password, and tried the same .
I got the same result as before.

This means that , the linux terminal not using the proxy server.

Why and how to make linux terminal use the proxy server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `http_proxy` environment variable will only be used:

- for HTTP requests
- by software that pays attention to it

The terminal doesn't make HTTP requests. It just displays a shell for you.

Ping doesn't make HTTP requests. It uses ICMP, not HTTP.

If you want to test your proxy, then you'll need to use software which does make an HTTP request, such as [Lynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)).

Comment: Can we set proxy for ICMP as like we set for HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your proxy information to `apt.conf` located in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.

In the `apt.conf`, add the following:

`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://<user_name>:<password>@<proxy address>:<port>";`